# Write notes under tables generated with stargazer

Tags: tables, database, statistics

I created these descriptive statistics table using the ``stargazer" package, in RStudio and I would like to write a note under this table, but I am not able to. The only thing I could do was a note, that could not be justified.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}

\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{frame}{Expected results}
% Table created by stargazer v.5.2.2 by Marek Hlavac, Harvard University. E-mail: hlavac at fas.harvard.edu
% Date and time: Wed, Oct 21, 2020 - 15:39:55
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{Descriptive statistics} 
  \label{} 
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!} {%
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lccccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Variable & \multicolumn{1}{c}{N} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{St. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Min} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Max} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Child deaths caused by infectious diseases & 28,119 & 0.486 & 2.487 & 0 & 230 \\ 
Access to piped water and sewage (\%) & 28,119 & 57.197 & 29.119 & 0.000 & 99.474 \\ 
Illiteracy rate (\%) & 28,119 & 30.453 & 15.129 & 2.022 & 70.261 \\ 
Years of schooling (population above 25) & 28,119 & 3.780 & 1.217 & 0.814 & 8.577 \\ 
Gini index & 28,119 & 0.582 & 0.092 & 0.364 & 0.880 \\ 
Population & 28,119 & 23,850.370 & 116,238.000 & 958 & 10,434,252 \\ Income per capita (R\$)  & 28,119 & 148.598 & 84.234 & 34.527 & 762.052 \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular}%
}


\end{table} 
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the issue itself, but don't use `resizebox` on  a table as this approach will result in inconsistent and sometimes illegibly small font sizes.

Comment: What kind of note would you like to add below the table? Just a few words or a longer text? Will you refer to this note inside of the table?

Comment: @leandriis, it is like four lines of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `\resizebox` I suggest using `tabularx` in combination with a smaller font size and a reduced `\tabcolsep`. In the following example, I also replaced the horizontal lines by lines from the `booktabs` package and added a small vertical white space ebtween adjacent rows as a guide to the eye. For the table note, I used a `\multicolumn`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{Expected results}

\begin{table}[!htbp] 
\centering 
\footnotesize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\setlength{\defaultaddspace}{0.9pt}
\caption{Descriptive statistics} 
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xccccc@{}} 
\toprule 
Variable & N & Mean & St. Dev. & Min & Max \\ 
\midrule
Child deaths caused by infectious diseases & 28,119 & 0.486      & 2.487       & 0      & 230        \\ \addlinespace
Access to piped water and sewage (\%)      & 28,119 & 57.197     & 29.119      & 0.000  & 99.474     \\ \addlinespace
Illiteracy rate (\%)                       & 28,119 & 30.453     & 15.129      & 2.022  & 70.261     \\ \addlinespace
Years of schooling (population above 25)   & 28,119 & 3.780      & 1.217       & 0.814  & 8.577      \\ \addlinespace
Gini index                                 & 28,119 & 0.582      & 0.092       & 0.364  & 0.880      \\ \addlinespace
Population                                 & 28,119 & 23,850.370 & 116,238.000 & 958    & 10,434,252 \\ \addlinespace
Income per capita (R\$)                    & 28,119 & 148.598    & 84.234      & 34.527 & 762.052    \\ 
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{6}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{The table shows the descriptive statistics of the data used in the paper. Child deaths caused by infectious diseases were obtained in the dataset. Access to piped water, illiteracy rate, years of schooling of the population above 25, Gini index, population, and income per capita were all obtained in the Ipeadata that uses the data provided by the 2000 census.}
\end{tabularx}
\end{table} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Since all entries in the "N"  column are basically identical, couls you remove that column entirely and add this information into the caption of your table? The result could look something like the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{Expected results}

\begin{table}[!htbp] 
\centering 
\footnotesize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\setlength{\defaultaddspace}{2.75pt}
\caption{Descriptive statistics; N = 28,119} 
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xcccc@{}} 
\toprule 
Variable                                   & Mean       & St. Dev.    & Min    & Max \\ 
\midrule
Child deaths caused by infectious diseases & 0.486      & 2.487       & 0      & 230        \\ \addlinespace
Access to piped water and sewage (\%)      & 57.197     & 29.119      & 0.000  & 99.474     \\ \addlinespace
Illiteracy rate (\%)                       & 30.453     & 15.129      & 2.022  & 70.261     \\ \addlinespace
Years of schooling (population above 25)   & 3.780      & 1.217       & 0.814  & 8.577      \\ \addlinespace
Gini index                                 & 0.582      & 0.092       & 0.364  & 0.880      \\ \addlinespace
Population                                 & 23,850.370 & 116,238.000 & 958    & 10,434,252 \\ \addlinespace
Income per capita (R\$)                    & 148.598    & 84.234      & 34.527 & 762.052    \\ 
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{5}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{The table shows the descriptive statistics of the data used in the paper. Child deaths caused by infectious diseases were obtained in the dataset. Access to piped water, illiteracy rate, years of schooling of the population above 25, Gini index, population, and income per capita were all obtained in the Ipeadata that uses the data provided by the 2000 census.}
\end{tabularx}
\end{table} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the table does not fit the slide. The text that I want to write is this one: "the table shows the descriptive statistics of the data used in the paper. Child deaths caused by infectious diseases were obtained in the dataset. Access to piped water, illiteracy rate, years of schooling of the population above 25, Gini index, population, and income per capita were all obtained in the Ipeadata that uses the data provided by the 2000 census."

Comment: @MateusMaciel: I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you looking for something like this:

[image]

With use of the `threeparttable`, `cellspace` and `siunitx` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, threeparttable}
\usepackage[column=O]{cellspace}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Expected results}
    \begin{table}
    \footnotesize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont
    \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
    \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Descriptive statistics}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                             O{m{0.33\linewidth}} 
                             S[table-format=5.0]
                        *{2}{S[table-format=2.3]}
                             S[table-format=1.3]
                             S[table-format=2.3]}
    \toprule
Variable & {N} & {Mean} & {St. Dev.} & {Min} & {Max} \\
    \midrule
Child deaths caused by infectious diseases 
    & 28 119 & 0.486 & 2.487 & 0 & 230 \\
Access to piped water and sewage (\%) 
    & 28 119 & 57.197 & 29.119 & 0.000 & 99.474 \\
Illiteracy rate (\%) 
    & 28 119 & 30.453 & 15.129 & 2.022 & 70.261 \\
Years of schooling (population above 25) 
    & 28 119 & 3.780 & 1.217 & 0.814 & 8.577 \\
Gini index 
    & 28 119 & 0.582 & 0.092 & 0.364 & 0.880 \\
Population 
    & {28 119} & {23 850 370} & {116 238 000} & {958}    & {10 434 252} \\ 
Income per capita (R\$)  
    & {28 119} & {148 598}    & {84 234}      & {34 527} & {762 052} \\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\end{tabular*}\scriptsize
    \begin{tablenotes}[para, flushleft]
    \item[*]    \(p<0.1\)
    \item[**]   \(p<0.01\)
    \item[***]  \(p<0.001\)
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
With desired text below the table, instead `threeparttable` is used ˙[referable]{threeparttablex}`, text in the first column is in one line

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[column=O]{cellspace}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Expected results}
    \begin{table}
    \footnotesize
    \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{2pt}
    \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{2pt}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Descriptive statistics for $N=\num{28 112}$}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                             Ol
                        *{2}{S[table-format=2.3]}
                             S[table-format=1.3]
                             S[table-format=2.3]}
    \toprule
Variable    & {Mean} & {St. Dev.} & {Min} & {Max} \\
    \midrule
Child deaths caused by infectious diseases
            &  0.486 &  2.487     & 0     & 230     \\
Access to piped water and sewage (\%)
            & 57.197 & 29.119     & 0.000 & 99.474  \\
Illiteracy rate (\%)
            & 30.453 & 15.129     & 2.022 & 70.261  \\
Years of schooling (population above 25)
            & 3.780  & 1.217      & 0.814 & 8.577   \\
Gini index
            & 0.582  & 0.092      & 0.364 & 0.880   \\
    \addlinespace
Population
            & {23 850 370} & {116 238 000} & {958}    & {10 434 252} \\
Income per capita (R\$)
            & {148 598}    & {84 234}      & {34 527} & {762 052} \\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\end{tabular*}\scriptsize
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
\note{
the table shows the descriptive statistics of the data used in the paper. Child deaths caused by infectious diseases were obtained in the dataset. Access to piped water, illiteracy rate, years of schooling of the population above 25, Gini index, population, and income per capita were all obtained in the Ipeadata that uses the data provided by the 2000 census.
    }    
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```